# SSRS take leading Zero out from a number

Tags: reporting-services, leading-zero

How can I always take the leading zero from my number? I tried many things but still i was not able to take out the leading zeros. Replace function wonot do the trick! coz it will take all zeros out.

Example:

00672656    ---> should be 672656

02074310    ---> Should be 2074310

Answer (score 0):

=CInt(Fields.YourColumn.Value)

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.